# Select Categories that have Products with a certain attribute

Tags: attributes, category, product-attribute, query, selection

My products have an attribute with possible values like "Shampoo", "Masque", etc...

How do i select all sub categories of the current category that contain products of type eg "Shampoo". I want to list **categories**, not products.

Thank you

Comment: For what purpose? Are you referring to frontend or backend?

Comment: I am referring to Frontend. For design purposes. I want to create a page to list only (sub)categories (not products) with the option to filter them based on their products.

Comment: My page is ready. What i need is a way to filter the categories using Magento's ORM.

Answer (score 1):

First get the current category.
Let's say it has the id 4.

```
$currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4);
```

Depending on context you might be able to get it like this:

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

Now get all the products with the value 'shampoo' for your attribtue.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('your_attribute_code', 'Shampoo'); 
    //if your attribute is dropdown then replace 'Shampoo' with the id of the option
$collection->addCategoryFilter($currentCategory); //filter products only from the current category if needed
```

get all children of the current category.

```
$children = $currentCategory->getChildrenCategories();
```

add the product count to the children collection

```
$collection->addCountToCategories($children);
```

Then you can loop through all the children and see if `product_count` is bigger than 0.

```
foreach ($children as $child) {
    if ($child->getProductCount() > 0) {
        //do something with $child.
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain it a little bit? I tried and seemed like `$child->getProductCount()` always return 0.

Comment: @kostaskostarelo. This is strange. It worked for me. I took the code from the layered navigation.  Look how the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category::_getItemsData` works.

Answer (score 0):

`$childCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()->addAttributeToFiler('parent_id',$current_cat_Id)
->addAttributeFilter('entity_id');`

```
$chhid=array();
foreach($childCat as $t)
{
   $chhid[]=$t->getId();
}


 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('your_attribute_code', 'Shampoo'); 

 $collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
     array('finset' => implode( $chhid)),
 );
  $collection->groupByAttribute(category_id');
```

Comment: your code doesn't work. :/

Comment: I just want to add selected category in observer, how can i call selected category? @Amit